# PhpStorm returns 502 bad gateway when sending blobs

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

So I am trying to send images to the browser as BLOBs that I retrieve from a MYSql database but every time I try to run my code it gives me a 502 Bad Gateway which doesn't seem to make any sense to me because I'm running it from localhost. I imagine this has to do with a size limit with the request. I was wondering if anyone knew what this problem might be and if there might be a better solution for it?

Comment: Where does PhpStorm fit into the picture? Check your Apache error log.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I was assuming that PhpStorm was running the server but didn't stop to think that it wasn't. I'm still under to much of an ASP.NET umbrella. Thanks I'll look into that

Comment: What URLs are look like? The Question here is -- are you using PhpStorm's own built-in wimple web server or your own Apache/nginx/IIS/whatever?

Comment: @LazyOne I'm using Xampp for my interpreter and I'm assuming that includes the apache webserver

Comment: In such case I do not see how it can be PhpStorm related issue here...